# How to assign a name for a node ?AM I missing something here?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct list
    {
        char name[20];
        int age;
        double height;
        list *next;
    };
    list *first, *temp, *temp2, *newlist1;
    first->next = temp;
    temp->next = temp2;
    newlist1 = new list;
    newlist1->name = "Steve";
    newlist1->age = 23;
    newlist1->height = 2.3;
    newlist1->next = temp2;
    temp->next = newlist1;
    newlist1->next = temp2;
    temp->next = newlist1;
    temp2 = newlist1->next;
    temp2->next = newlist1->next;
    delete temp2;
    cout << " Name is: " << newlist1->name << " ";
    cout << " Age is: " << newlist1->age << " ";
    cout << " Height is: " << newlist1->height;
}
```

Is this how you assign the name value to a node? ...I tried strcpy but it keeps saying strcpy isn't declared...or something else. Can someone please show me a code on how to assign name[20] char types onto a node please? I'm really having a problem with this :(

Answer (score 1):

strcpy is part of the standard C library. Its function declaration needs to be #included in order for the compiler to know what it is. Try adding `#include <cstring>` at the beginning of the file.

However, since you are using C++, my real recommendation would be to switch to using the C++ standard string class. It's a lot easier, safer, and more C++-ish to use it.... In order to use that, `#include <string`> and then change your declaration to `std::string name;`

Another problem you're going to run into shortly is that you are only allocating 1 list object (newlist1), but are referencing, for example, `first->next` when `first` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use raw `char` arrays. Add a "`#include <string>`" to the top and use "`string`" instead:

```
#include <string>
 .
 .
 .
struct list
{
    string name;
 .
 .
 .
```

If you must use raw `char` arrays, you're doing it wrong. Look up the "`strcpy`" function.

Answer (score -1):

Your assignment:

```
newlist1->name = "Steve";
```

Is incorrect. Because `name` is a `char[20]` and not a `char *`, this sort of assignment will not work.

You can use `strcpy` for this if you'd like:

```
strcpy(newlist1->name, "Steve");
```

It's a simple solution to your problem, but as you learn more you would likely not want to do these things in this way later on. (opting for 'safer' methods, such as `strncpy`, for example).

Comment: ...a downvote for a correct answer that actually addresses the question that was posed, without any justification given? Nice.